# How to write a regex to filter an {key:value} string

Tags: objective-c, regex

I  have a string like this

```
    NSString *content = @"{"year":2019,"month":12,"day":08}";
```

How can i get the value for year,month and day?

```
NSRegularExpression *testExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(\w+):(\w+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [testExpression matchesInString:content
                                               options:0
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])];
```

Comment: Regex? Isn't that some JSON? Instead, learn how to parse JSON?

Comment: @Larme， yes, it's json. But will be parsed fail since the day is "08" which was leading with zero.

Comment: Good point, it might have been a good information to add to your question. I then though about making it valid JSON. Using regex `@"(:)(\\d+)"`, you'll convert the "Int" into Strings, and the remplacement template would be `@"$1\"$2\""`.